# Angular 2 - *ngFor with checkbox and corresponding label

Tags: angular

im working on a data-table in Angular 2.

My `<table-component>` is a regular `<table>` and inside I'm trying to multiply `<tr>`s using Angular's *ngFor, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="#person of persons; #i = index">
```

Every `<tr>` has a couple of fields and one `checkbox` with a `label`.

I set the id attribute of the `checkbox` like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{i}}">
<label for="checkbox{{i}}">{{person.finished}}</label>
```

Where {{i}} is the local variable from ngFor. And it works fine, but only for the checkbox.

When I try to do the same for the atrribute "for" in the `label` I only get errors.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a known native property ("
   <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{i}}">
        <label [ERROR ->]for="checkbox{{i}}">{{person.finished}}</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

My question is:

How can I set the "for" attribute of the labels using Angular 2's ngFor, so they point to the right checkbox?

Answer (score 15):

You should use the following to set the attribut value:

```
<label [attr.for]="'checkbox'+i">{{person.finished}}</label>
```

Comment: could you publish a complete example?